# Type that could be Int, Float or Double

Tags: swift

I have production code that is parsing JSON. In my unit tests I want to duplicate what is happening in this code. You can see in the screenshot that after parsing the JSON the type is `Optional<Any>`. This can be cast to Int, Float or Double.

What type does `testValue` need to be to behave the same way as `json["percentage"]`?

[image: Playgounds Screenshot]

```
import Foundation

let jsonString = "{\"percentage\":23}"
let jsonData = jsonString.data(using: .utf8)!
let json = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options: []) as! [String: Any]

let typeOfPercentage = type(of: json["percentage"])
let floatPercent = json["percentage"] as? Float
let doublePercent = json["percentage"] as? Double
let intPercent = json["percentage"] as? Int

let testValue: Any? = 23.0 // !!!!!!!!!!!
let floatPercent2 = testValue as? Float
let doublePercent2 = testValue as? Double
let intPercent2 = testValue as? Int
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON parsing is actually giving you an `NSNumber` for the value of `json["percentage"]`.

It comes across as an optional `Any` because the dictionary is declared as `[String:Any]` and accessing a dictionary value via a key gives you an optional because the key might not exist in the dictionary.

If you change:

```
let testValue: Any? = 23.0
```

to:

```
let testValue: NSNumber = 23.0
```

then your last three lines will give you `23` as a result since `NSNumber` can be cast to those other types (the joy of bridging the Objective-C `NSNumber` to Swift native number types).

Comment: It will fail in case of `let intPercent2 = testValue as? Int`, if we pass `testValue` as `23.5`, then it returning `nil`.

Comment: @technerd Good point but then if the original JSON has `23.5` then the value of `intPercent` will also be `nil`. So the behavior is the same and using `NSNumber` is still the correct answer.

Comment: So can we make it like it returns round value like `23.0` or `24.0` for `23.5` in case of `Int`?

Comment: @technerd Sure, you can get the `Double` and then convert it to `Int`, rounding in the process if desired.

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can use `Double` & type cast as you need later

as

```
let testValue: Double = 23.5
let floatPercent = Float(testValue)//prints 23.5
let intPercent = Int(testValue)//prints 23
```

Comment: Sorry, can you explain ? , `type(of: T)` where T is generic.